# Problem in redirect link in wordpress

Tags: wp-redirect

I created a login page in wordpress and redirected the page to another website . Now, after clicking the login icon from the menubar it redirects to another page. Thats fine. But I cant access the wp-admin page to edit the wordpress because whenever I go to wp-admin (www.energymaterials.org/wp-admin) , it again redirects to another page. I cant go to my admin page, of course the login in the menu bar redirects to the page (www.energymaterials.org -> select login in the menu bar->it will redirect to another site) which i redirected but i cant access my own admin page which is the most important page. How to sort out this issue ? Please help me.

Comment: Show the redirect code Please. You must have integrated some kind of code to redirect to your custom page. I assume this code is responsible for that behaviour

Comment: http://172.16.18.166:4000/ This is my redirect ip address . I did not use any code to redirect the page. I just pasted this ip address inside the wordpress edit options redirect page.

Comment: there is no WordPress edit options redirect page. Are you sure it's not a plugin adding this behaviour?

Comment: I am sure its not a plugin.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure. Shall I delete the plugin which might be suspicious for this behaviour from my local winscp?

Comment: deactivate it and check if you can access wp-admin again

Comment: Yeah thank you so much . You have resolved my issue. I deleted the concerned plugin and now I can access the admin page.

Comment: Glad it worked.i will add it as answer so you can accept it to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to the comments.

As there is no redirection page from WordPress itself, please check if you have some plugins enabled that create this page. deactivate them to test if you can access your wp-admin again.